# Table and Chart with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, charts

by using NodeJS or Javascript only, I want to create a simple web page containing a chart and a data table for that chart. After that, I wanna save the table and chart in a PDF file.
**IMPORTANT**: My device, where the web page will keep running, is stand alone and once it's running it'll be connected to a network WITHOUT internet access. That is, it'll be necessary to install everything on device (no problem!), because it'll not be able to get access to external components ou resources.

How can I create the chart and table on web page and save to PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jsPDF located here  https://parall.ax/products/jspdf and below is a working example

```js
var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

```js
var chart_data = {
  labels: ['Player1', 'Player2', 'Player3', 'Player4'],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(6, 118, 152, 0.71)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [20, 34, 15, 64, ]
  }]
}

//original canvas
var canvas = document.querySelector('#cool-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

new Chart(context).Line(chart_data);

//hidden canvas
var newCanvas = document.querySelector('#supercool-canvas');
newContext = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

var supercoolcanvas = new Chart(newContext).Line(chart_data);
supercoolcanvas.defaults.global = {
  scaleFontSize: 600
}

//add event listener to button
document.getElementById('download-pdf').addEventListener("click", downloadPDF);

//donwload pdf from original canvas
function downloadPDF() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('#cool-canvas');
  //creates image
  var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

  //creates PDF from img
  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
  doc.setFontSize(20);
  doc.text(15, 15, "Cool Chart");
  doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 280, 150);
  doc.save('canvas.pdf');
}

//add event listener to 2nd button
document.getElementById('download-pdf2').addEventListener("click", downloadPDF2);

//download pdf form hidden canvas
function downloadPDF2() {
  var newCanvas = document.querySelector('#supercool-canvas');

  //create image from dummy canvas
  var newCanvasImg = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

  //creates PDF from img
  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
  doc.setFontSize(20);
  doc.text(15, 15, "Super Cool Chart");
  doc.addImage(newCanvasImg, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 280, 150);
  doc.save('new-canvas.pdf');
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="cool-canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="height:0; width:0; overflow:hidden;">
  <canvas id="supercool-canvas" width="1200" height="600"></canvas>
</div>

<button type="button" id="download-pdf">
  Download PDF
</button>

<button type="button" id="download-pdf2">
  Download Higher Quality PDF
</button>
```

Comment: Great! 
Two questions more: 
1) Everything I put on page will be saved in pdf file, including a simple data table? 
2) How can I create a chart on the same page? 
thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your attention to the previous answer, but I'm not asking you to solve the problem with the complete code. I just don't know if it can be done or not. I had heard of jsPDF, as well as other tools, and I'll try to use it. But when I'm going to start something, if I don't know how to start I always ask someone before the beginning. In my initial question I asked for chart and so I repeated the question to take advantage of this topic. But OK! In the next time I'll separe in two posts. Thank you.

Comment: @wBB you can show appreciation by selecting the answer.

Comment: I can't do this because my question wasn't answered. The title of the question is "Table and Chart with Javascript" and I also ask how to save this content in PDF. You gave me a hint just about the PDF file. The main part, that is, about chart, wasn't answered. If I select your answer, it will lead others to an incomplete response. I still thank you for your help.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry! I haven't seen. I run the code here in the "Run the code snippet" section and the graphic has a white background. In the PDF file created has a black background. This is a problem? Could your solution be run without internet access on the local machine? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you just need to download the external scripts/lib. Use npm or bower.

Comment: I'll try to use all your tips. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have so far tried to install jsPDF on Windows, but to no avail yet. When running `npm install -g jspdf`several errors appear. I have seen in some places someone suggest downloading the zip file from github master and I tried it too, but it didn't work. Have you seen this happen?

Comment: is your version of node up to date? you can also just copy the js from the cdn , however, there might be other dependencies.also make sure to require it where you are using it .

Comment: Yes they are not the latest versions, but almost everything is updated.
Npm: '4.4.4', node: '6.10.2'. When I create a script with `var jsPDF = require ('node-jspdf');` or `var jsPDF = require ('jspdf');` the error "Error: Can not find module 'node-jspdf'" appears. I'm already tired ...